# Ubuntu virtual connection between network Applications

Tags: network-programming, virtual, ubuntu-12.04

I try to connect two applictaions on one Ubuntu 12.04.01 LTS Sytsem. The Applications communicate over MAC addresses.

For example:

application 1 connect to a network interface with MAC_address 00:11:22:33:44:55.

application 2 connect to a network interface with MAC_address 00:11:22:33:44:56.

I've try many solutions: MACVLAN, TUNTAPdevices, Tap with bridge, Tap connection over GNS3 and LXC with NS3.

But my Problem is I should run the Applications on one Hostsystem, without changes in the applicationsettings. No one of the solutions works correct. It should work like a virtual Ethernet. The applications send and receive ethernet II packets.

Have someone a idea, how can i solve this Problem?

Thank you forward.

Answer (score 0):

try sending it to localhost (127.0.0.1) but for different ports.
Example:

```
application 1 runs on 127.0.0.1:1000 -> application 2 runs on 127.0.0.1:2000

application 2 runs on 127.0.0.1:2000 -> application 1 runs on 127.0.0.1:1000
```